# In version AEM 6.3, is it possible to have a component render without the 'aem-GridColumn' class(es)?

Tags: aem

This is what is being rendered:

```
<div class="aem--inline-span aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12 cq-Editable-dom">
    <a class="btn learn-more">
        Contact Sales
    </a>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd have mark up that looks something like this:

```
<div class="aem--inline-span cq-Editable-dom">
    <a class="btn learn-more">
        Contact Sales
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to avoid using a JavaScript hack for this.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aem-GridColumn` classes are added because you are making use of the responsive parsys (`wcm/foundation/components/responsivegrid`) and it's associated "Layouting" mode.

To prevent these classes from being added, you need to use the normal parsys (`wcm/foundation/components/parsys`).

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/operations/page-authoring/configuring-responsive-layouting.html

Comment: is this possibile in aem 6.5 also?